Shopware 6 SHOPWARE_CDN_STRATEGY_DEFAULT has no effect
I updated Shopware 6.5.8.11 to 6.6.3.0 and now are all image paths different for some reason.
I tried to set
SHOPWARE_CDN_STRATEGY_DEFAULT="id"
and
SHOPWARE_CDN_STRATEGY_DEFAULT="filename"
But the generated paths didn't change at all, no matter what value I set.
Usually problems like this are resolved by switching back and forth this setting.
I checked the spelling multiple times and copied it from other posts, but it doesn't change anything. I also checked if there is another entry in the .env file.
Did anyone ever encountered this behaviour?
I found this on Google, which seems to be the root of the problem:
https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/adr/2023-08-17-media-path.html
But not sure how to adapt to these changes.
